# xcode error message when I'm trying to Archive my project: line 7: /resources-to-copy-project.txt: Permission denied

Tags: xcode, cordova

I'm trying to Archive my project in xcode. When I press run everything working fine and I can test my app on my ios device. I'm using cordova for all things. Now when I want to Archive project I got some type of error message:

> /Users/eUser/ui_app/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-project/Pods-project-resources.sh: line 7: /resources-to-copy-project.txt: Permission denied

Any solution for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310851/xcode-error-when-building-app-line-7-resources-to-copy-project-txt-permissio/48634353#48634353

Answer (score -1):

I also faced exactly the same issue.

This works for me:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 Project-folder
```