# Cannot build pod dependent iOS project in offline

Tags: ios, cocoapods, rsync, permission-denied, build-error

I need to build an iOS project which has pod dependency for couple of frameworks. Getting below build error for the project which was buildable previously when was online.

> rsync: failed to open files-from file Repo/Pods/resources-to-copy-Project.txt: Permission denied
>
> Unexpected Failure

Similar [issue has been raised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45310851/1084174) but solution does not work for my case. In my project I found no script like `"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Pods-resources.sh"`

**How to resolve it?** My Mac is offline and I cannot run `pod install` anymore. Just need to build previously buildable project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This issue has been resolved by removing `[CP] Copy Pod Resources` step from `Build phase` tab.**

Actually cocoapods autogenerates this step for cocoapods **v5.x** which is no longer been used after **6.x** but cocoapod updates could not able to handle migration case properly. So, if your project went through that migration period this issue might happen.